# CoordinatorLayout scrolling does not work while Toolbar is added via <include layout =" " />

Tags: android, android-toolbar, coordinator-layout, android-include, android-scrollable-tabs

So i have been learning a tutorial to hide tool bar in CoordinatorLayout while i scroll up my view pagers first fragment but toolbar is not moving up or hiding while i scroll up.

The toolbar is added in Coordinator layout using < include layout / > tag.

But when i add tool bar directly whithout referencing it using < include layout / > (adding toolbar in Coordinator layout the way we add. **DEFAULT WAY**) the toolbar slides up and works.

Here is both .xml code, i dont understand why Coordinator Layout is not working with < include/> tag ?

**Coordinator With include...**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout BLAH BLAH BLAH >

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

Toolbar is not responding to scroll **BUT**

**Coordinator without custom Toolbar..**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout BLAH BLAH BLAH >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

**It WORKS! O.O BUT HOW ? And why < include tag is not working ?**

**here is my custom toolbar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the line

app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

to inside toolbar_main.xml
instead of the include statement

Comment: Thanks, It actually is working now. just dont know why it is not working when i use it in < include tag. i read it that you can use custom xml with < include tag and if you add any extra attributes to < include, it will still work the same as it works without it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯